# design change and google sitelinks

Tags: google, sitelinks

I have a site where google display sitelinks on search results. I want to implement a new design where all sitelink targets would chage.

Is that a good idea? Would google drop those links? What would I need to get google update links? For example would permanent redirection of links on new design help?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI

Comment: thats where i am trying to move to

Answer (score 1):

If you make sure that your old URLs redirect to the new ones then you should be OK. Your old page should redirect to the new one using HTTP status of 301 "moved permanently".

If you don't put the redirects in then all existing links are broken and Google *may* see your new URLs as duplicate content of the old and not rank them so well.